# using array[i][j] in a CUDA kernel memcpy call

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I have an array that is of the following design: `color[100][3]`. I want to populate this array in a kernel and then use it in host code. How can I accomplish this? I simply need the `cudaMemcpy()` call to send and get.

This is what I have to send to device:

```
err = cudaMallocPitch(&d_color, &pitch, 3 * sizeof(unsigned char),100);
```

This is what I have now to get it from device (Edited):

```
err = cudaMemcpy2D(color,100*3,d_color,pitch,3 *sizeof(unsigned char),3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

The last call of cudaMemcpy2D throws an error of:

> "Invalid Argument"

How do I get the pitch of the `color[100][3]` array? Should I assume it is `3+1` padded?

Comment: Why don't you use the normal `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaMemcpy()`? You just need a pointer to the memory.

Comment: Map your 2D array into 1D array. In call kernel pass another parameter, which will tell you, how long is one dimension, i.e `color[100 * 3]` and pass 100 as dimSize and you can access 253th elements using `color[i/*53*/ + dim /*2nd*/ * N /* 100 */] = 0;`

Comment: I would but this array is apart of the Cimg framework. I have to use it as is because code behind uses the array in this fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
err = cudaMemcpy2D(
        color, 
        pitch, 
        d_color, 
        sizeof(unsigned char) * 100 * 3, // <<< WRONG - source pitch, not it's size!
        3 * sizeof(unsigned char), 
        100 * sizeof(unsigned char), // <<< Shouldn't it be number of rows, not column size in bytes?
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost
        );
```

Btw - wouldn't it be easier to use uchar3 type?

Comment: ah yes i've mixed up some parameters. Ive made the following changes and i still get a seg fault: err = cudaMemcpy2D(color,100*3,d_color,pitch,3 *sizeof(unsigned char),3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

Comment: how do i get the pitch of the color[100][3] array?

Comment: I would use uchar3 but the CImg library and this particular array is used as an unsigned char in the framework. Im trying to upgrade a routine in the framework to use the CUDA gpu.

Comment: Try: `cudaMemcpy2D(color, pitch, d_color, pitch, 3 *sizeof(unsigned char), 100, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`.